# Reprojecting Natural Earth "Admin 0 – Countries" shapefile to Web Mercator

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, web-mercator

I haven't received a reply posting this same question on the Natural Earth forums, so I figured I'd give it a try here.

I’m trying to reproject the [1:10m "Admin 0 – Countries"](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) shapefile into a Web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857) using QGIS. However, the reprojection fails with the following message:

```
Export to vector file failed. Error: Failed to transform a point while
drawing a feature of type ‘ne_10m_admin_0_countries’. Writing stopped.
(Exception: forward transform of (3.141593, -1.570796) PROJ.4:
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
Error: tolerance condition error)
```

I receive this error for both "[ne_10m_admin_0_countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip)" and "[ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.zip)".

[A post here on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/why-do-i-get-failed-to-transform-when-reprojecting-from-wgs84-to-google-mercat) indicates that it might be a problem with points in Antarctica going to infinity during reprojection, but I’m not sure how to fix it if that is indeed the problem.

The [1:50m "Admin 0 – Countries"](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/) shapefiles are able to be reprojected successfully using QGIS, which leads me to believe that the root of the problem may lie in the 1:10m shapefiles.

I'm hoping that someone can expand on the answer offered in the [linked post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/why-do-i-get-failed-to-transform-when-reprojecting-from-wgs84-to-google-mercat) and provide answers for the following questions:

- Is there an error in the 1:10m shapefile? (Since the 1:50m shapefile reprojects without issue) Or is this sort of reprojection error just to be expected under certain circumstances?
- **Exactly what steps may I take to fix the shapefile so that it can be successfully reprojected?** The [linked post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/why-do-i-get-failed-to-transform-when-reprojecting-from-wgs84-to-google-mercat) says to "delete the objects around the south pole" but I'd prefer not to delete Antarctica. I tried editing the Antarctica feature to chop off the southernmost portion, but it didn't seem resolve the reprojection error.

Please assume I'm a GIS newbie.

Thanks!

**RESOLUTION & NEW SHAPEFILES**

Second try was the charm for me, and I was able to trim off the bottom of Antarctica using the "Reshape Feature" tool in QGIS. There's a decent description of how to use it here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21651/1770. After removing the southernmost portion of Antarctica, I was able to successfully reproject the map.

To save everyone some time, I've posted the files. These are the "_lakes" files that do NOT include boundary lakes:

- Original file in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326), but with the bottom 0.4 degrees of Antarctica trimmed off. You should be able to reproject this file without issue: https://github.com/dmillz/misc/raw/master/shapefiles/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes-trimmed_antarctica.zip
- Same file, but reprojected into Web Mercator (EPSG:3857): https://github.com/dmillz/misc/raw/master/shapefiles/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes-EPSG_3857.zip

Comment: the post you link to contains a clear answer to your problem

Comment: The post I link to does not answer the following questions: Is there an error in the 1:10m shapefile (since the 1:50m shapefile reprojects just fine)? How may I go about fixing the shapefile so that it can be reprojected? All the post says is "delete the objects around the south pole", and I'd prefer not to delete Antarctica.

Comment: Don't try to project files that contain data north or south of 85 degrees in to Google Mercator.

Comment: The 1:50m shapefile contains data south of 85 degrees and reprojects without issue. Also, I'm still interested in an answer to both of my questions. Exactly what steps may I take to fix the 1:10m shapefile so that it can be successfully reprojected?

Comment: I re-opened the Q since David revised it sufficiently to show what makes this different from the linked duplicate. However since it is a specialized problem relating to a single dataset there is potential for it to be closed again as 'too localized'. We'll see what kind of answers are turned up.

Comment: Exactly what I need, using your EPSG:3857 projection for an OpenStreetMap prototype I'm working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is reasonably clear--there's a problem at longitude = 180, latitude = -90 (given values are in radians). I downloaded both datasets and displayed them together in ArcMap. When I checked Antarctica, the 1:50 million data has its southernmost line at approximately -89.9989, while the 1:10 million is -90.0. Clip off the bottom of Antarctica slightly and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ok, second time was the charm for me. I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time when attempting to chop off the bottom of Antarctica, but the key tool to use in QGIS is called "Reshape Feature". There a decent description of how to use it here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21651/1770. After removing the southernmost portion of Antarctica, I was able to successfully reproject the map.