# Cleaning GPX-Errors

Tags: qgis, gpx

we are currently tracking tourists at an open air museum in Austria. The museum is quite a large area and people walk or take the train. However if people go into the old houses/farms the signal often gets lost and causes errors. Being from the tourism community and not a GIS-professional, I searched for several days now, how to "clean" errors caused. (here is such a track with errors" - https://www.dropbox.com/s/jsp5zto54j826e9/Track-Errors.zip?dl=0). I found the way to mark the error points and to delete them in Qgis (select an object) but if I delete it, I delete the whole track. I just want to delete this specific error-point and not the whole track.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the node tool  [image: Node Tool] in QGIS to delete just the node not the whole line, to do the edit's I think you need to save the layer as a shapefile shp or another editable format first.

Select your layer.
Save as a shapefile
Enabled Editing.
Choose the Node Tool.

Click a point on your line.
(use control key to select multiple nodes)
Use Delete key to delete the selected points
save as a gpx file.

[How to remove a node in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166406/how-to-remove-a-node-in-qgis)

[Delete points on a polygon using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21630/delete-points-on-a-polygon-using-qgis)

Comment: There is also this stack exchange question which may be useful http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110331/how-to-clean-edit-gpx-tracks-files-recorded-from-gps-device